# Trailer about a movie with the same/similar concept as Among Us

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched a trailer a little over a month ago about a group of people who were sitting in a circle in these throne looking chairs. To escape they had to find the “Imposter” in the group, and so if I remember clearly, they were all sent to a random environment like the ocean and they had to get clues as to who was the killer and then they would “wake up” back at the circle with the thrones.

I watched this on YouTube and if I remember, it was something like upcoming movies of 2020-2021.

Comment: So basically *"[Mafia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mafia_(party_game)): The Movie"*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're thinking of [Survival Game](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4471388/?ref_=adv_li_tt), a Russian film from several years ago that is being released again dubbed into English.

> Moscow, 2072. Twelve contestants, each with their own story and motives, play a televised game of Mafia. Those eliminated must enter a virtual reality to conquer their worst fear - or die trying.

Here is the trailer:

Comment: Lol. It *is* Mafia the movie. I was only joking but there it is!